# Function length "a" does not compile, if OverloadedStrings extension is enabled

Tags: haskell

If "**{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}**" is included at the top of the source file, or in package.yaml (I am using stack), then

```
length "a"  -- does not compile anymore.
```

However the custom function `length'` is working fine

```
length' :: [a] -> Int 
length' xs = sum [1 | _ <- xs]
```

The package `Data.String` is imported - I  think the problem is there, but, I am interested to see, if somebody had similar problem.

Stack and GHC versions:
Version 2.3.1, Git revision x86_64 hpack-0.33.0, ghc-8.8.3

I am using mac osx, but the same error is in Linux and windows too.

## This is an error produced by stack:

```
/Users/admin1/Haskell/PROJECTS/orig1/src/Lib.hs:13:29: error:
    • Ambiguous type variables ‘t0’,
                               ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘"a"’
      prevents the constraint ‘(IsString (t0 a0))’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’,
                                                          ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (a ~ Char) => IsString [a] -- Defined in ‘Data.String’
        ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘length’, namely ‘"a"’
      In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(length "a")’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘show (length "a")’
   |
13 |     putStrLn $ show (length "a")  -- does not work, if "- OverloadedStrings" is on
```

Comment: This is because there can be sereval `Foldable`s.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner. Thank you for editing my funny post. It looks much better now. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because [**`length`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) has a signature `length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`, so it can be any `Foldable` type. If you use the `OverloadedStrings` extension, then `"foo"` is no longer a `String`, it can be any type `IsString a => a`, and multiple fo these can be `Foldable f => f a`s as well.

What you can do is give the compiler a type hint, for example with:

```
length ("a" :: String)
```

Comment: Thans a lot. It works now. As you probably understood I am new in Haskell.